# Vue.js Кнопка сохранить на админ панели

Tags: vue.js

Как сделать кнопку, которая будет сохранять измененные данные в тексте и заголовке на админ панели и переносить их на сайт.
Vue.js

Comment: Точнее она должна перезаписать эти изменения на бэкенде